# What is the difference between COUNT_SCAN and IXSCAN?

Tags: mongodb

Whenever I run a count query on MongoDB with explain I can see two different stages COUNT_SCAN and IXSCAN. I want to know the difference between them according to performance and how can I improve the query.
field is indexed.

following query:

```
db.collection.explain(true).count({field:1}})
```

uses COUNT_SCAN and query like:

```
db.collection.explain(true).count({field:"$in":[1,2]})
```

uses IXSCAN.

Answer (score 9):

The short: `COUNT_SCAN` is the most efficient way to get a count by reading the value from an index, but can only be performed in certain situations. Otherwise, `IXSCAN` is performed following by some filtering of documents and a count in memory.

When reading from secondary the read concern `available` is used. This concern level doesn't consider orphan documents in sharded clusters, and so no `SHARDING_FILTER` stage will be performed. This is when you see `COUNT_SCAN`.

However, if we use read concern `local`, we need to fetch the documents in order to perform the SHARDING_FILTER filter stage. In this case, there are multiple stages to fulfill the query: `IXSCAN`, then `FETCH` then `SHARDING_FILTER`.