# Can an indexed query count trigger a 'Mongo Query Targeting: Scanned Objects / Returned' alert?

Tags: mongodb

Hypothetical scenario (based on a more complex actual scenario):

1. A collection with a million documents, all following the simple schema of:

```
{
  _id: ...,
  message: string,
  createdAt: Date,
}
```

2. The collection has in index: `{createdAt: -1}` allowing for efficient querying and sorting of messages based on the date they were created
3. For the purposes of pagination and filtering, the front-end only displays x number of messages at a time alongside a count of the full number of available messages.

So for example, the UI would show the results of:

```
collection.find( 
  { createdAt: { $gte: 'some date', $lte: 'some other date' } }, 
  { limit: 20, sort: { createdAt: -1 } } 
)
```

And also show a count of the total matched documents for that query to determine if a 'load more' button should be present and to display the total count to the user:

```
// Do count functions like this trigger a query targeting alert if the count is high? 
// Even if the field is indexed?

collection.find( 
  { createdAt: { $gte: 'some date', $lte: 'some other date' } }
).count()
```

**Question: If the query in question: `{ createdAt: { $gte: 'some date', $lte: 'some other date' } }` , indexed though it is, has a total count of let's say 11,000 documents, would it trigger a Mongo Query Targeting: Scanned Objects / Returned alert if the threshold is 10,000 documents?**

Related question - is there a way for me to test things like this in isolation?

Comment: What is preventing you from running this query and observing the result?

Comment: you can use aggregate() along with [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) operator to achieve both pagination and total count, you can check the scanned document using [explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#return-information-on-aggregation-pipeline-operation).

Comment: You would need to use 'explain' to examine the query execution to see if it uses [count_scan or ixscan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554932/what-is-the-difference-between-count-scan-and-ixscan)

Comment: @D.SM - I just get the count and don't quite understand how to dive deeper (though I may have dived deeper without understanding what I'm seeing - see reply to Joe below).

Comment: @Joe - It is using an IXSCAN (I can see this from the Atlas Profiler). COUNTSCAN isn't a term I had come across and didn't realise that IXSCAN is not the best way for a count. I'll do my own research on that but am I right in assuming that the fact it is using an IXSCAN may mean it is scanning x documents and returning 0 documents, hence triggering the alert? Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Another point that may help your investigation - the alert is based on the server statistics for documents scanned and returned since it was last started, not any single query.  Look for the exact numbers used for that alert in the [serverStatus](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.serverStatus/index.html#db-serverstatus) output in `metrics.document.returned` and `metrics.queryExecutor.scannedObjects`