Mongo Data API find documents count
Can the total document count be extracted using Mongo Data API? If there are a million records in the Mongo DB collection I need the count.
Tried with Mongo data API /find the endpoint. But not sure if any timeout happens if querying the million of records.

Use the aggregation endpoint and put just one $count stage in the pipeline.

In addition to what @aneroid suggests, prior to $count use $sort on a field that is indexed to get the best performance.

Nice. thanks. Is there an aggregation endpoint in Mongo data API?

Got it,/data/v1/action/aggregate,thanks

@Joe I am not sure if a $sort will benefit the performance if appended before $count. It looks to me that we will dump the records themselves and just keep the count anyway. Do we still need the extra overhead to sort the data? If you are talking about putting $match to match existing indices, then everything makes sense to me.

@ray If there is an index that supports the sort, the server can use a COUNT_SCAN to get the count without loading the documents, which should perform quite a bit bettern than the COLLSCAN, which would read the entire collection.  A bit more detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58696903/2282634

Thanks @Joe. That's something new to me!

I tried with the aggregate endpoint. The request payload is {"collection":"test","database":"test","dataSource":"test","pipeline":"[{"$count": "name"}]"} but got 400 bad request.I think the payload is wrong. Any suggestion on what is missing?

Bad request due to pipeline argument must be an array
